# Select query timing out for just 17000 rows in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to identify the rows which when grouped at the highest level fail to reach a count which is greater than equal to a threshold value. If a row meets the threshold value at a lower grouping level then those rows are not considered for the higher level checks.

For example :

I have value like this and threshold is 5.

```
COL_1   COL_2   COL_3
CH  ZZZZZZ  T77613
CH  ZZZZZZ  R537973
**CH    181600  19M8323**
**CH    HYC440  RE575008**
**CH    211000  AE74215**
CH  ZZZZZZ  T77858
CH  ZZZZZZ  T76938
CH  ZZZZZZ  T77932
CH  ZZZZZZ  T76938
CH  ZZZZZZ  14M7396
CH  ZZZZZZ  RE593267
CH  ZZZZZZ  RE593267
CH  ZZZZZZ  RE579130
CH  ZZZZZZ  14M7296
CH  ZZZZZZ  RE580337
CH  ZZZZZZ  RE580337
```

only the bolded rows need to be selected .

I am using a query like below

```
WITH Step1 AS (
    SELECT x1.*
    FROM mytable AS x1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT col_1
            ,col_2
            ,col_3
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY col_1
            ,col_2
            ,col_3
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
        ) y1 ON x1.col_1 = y1.col_1
        AND x1.col_2 = y1.col_2
        AND x1.col_3 = y1.col_3
    WHERE y1.col_1 IS NULL
        AND y1.col_2 IS NULL
        AND y1.col_3 IS NULL
    )
,Step2 AS (
    SELECT x1.*
    FROM Step1 x1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT col_1
            ,col_2
        FROM Step1
        GROUP BY col_1
            ,col_2
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
        ) y1 ON x1.col_1 = y1.col_1
        AND x1.col_2 = y1.col_2
    WHERE y1.col_1 IS NULL
        AND y1.col_2 IS NULL
    )
,Step3 AS (
    SELECT x1.*
    FROM Step2 x1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT col_1
        FROM Step2
        GROUP BY col_1
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
        ) y1 ON x1.col_1 = y1.col_1
    WHERE y1.col_1 IS NULL
    )
SELECT *
FROM Step3
```

This query is giving the correct results. But once the table has more than around 17000 rows the sql query just hangs and times out.

Anyone know what is going wrong and any better solution one can provide ?

Update :

I found some answers from here https://www.sqlshack.com/why-is-my-cte-so-slow/ . After using a temp table to store the result of the first two CTEs , I was able to run the query and get results in 45 seconds.

```sql
WITH Step1 AS (
        SELECT x1.*
        FROM mytable AS x1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT col_1
                ,col_2
                ,col_3
            FROM mytable
            GROUP BY col_1
                ,col_2
                ,col_3
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
            ) y1 ON x1.col_1 = y1.col_1
            AND x1.col_2 = y1.col_2
            AND x1.col_3 = y1.col_3
        WHERE y1.col_1 IS NULL
            AND y1.col_2 IS NULL
            AND y1.col_3 IS NULL
        )
    ,Step2 AS (
        SELECT x1.*
        FROM Step1 x1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT col_1
                ,col_2
            FROM Step1
            GROUP BY col_1
                ,col_2
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
            ) y1 ON x1.col_1 = y1.col_1
            AND x1.col_2 = y1.col_2
        WHERE y1.col_1 IS NULL
            AND y1.col_2 IS NULL
        )

select * into #CTE2 from step2 ;

WITH Step3 AS (
        SELECT x1.*
        FROM #CTE2 x1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT col_1
            FROM Step2
            GROUP BY col_1
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
            ) y1 ON x1.col_1 = y1.col_1
        WHERE y1.col_1 IS NULL
        )
SELECT *
    FROM Step3 ;
```

But that does mean its not a single sql query anymore.

Comment: Can you format that wall of text into something legible? Nobody is going to want to decipher that. Also, can you try to explain the business logic here? What is this threshold value? What is a higher level? As posted this isn't answerable.

Comment: I am sorry for the formatting , i believe its now showing properly ? i have mentioned the threhold as 5 and you can see in my query where i check for count of 5. The highest grouping column here is Col_1 and the next lower grouping column is Col_2 and then Col_3

Comment: Query plan, tables and indices?

Comment: Are you wanting all rows where the count of Col1 and Col2 is less than 5?

Comment: I don't have the query plan. there is an index on col1,col2,col3 and another column. Its a Microsoft SQL Server Database ( AWS RDS ).

Comment: @SeanLange , No . the count of rows when grouped at col_1 level falls below 5.But with the condition that the rows which we consider for checking the count cannot be grouped at any lower level with count reaching 5.

Comment: What does lower level mean? You have obfuscated this so much that is makes no sense. You might want to review [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear at all, but as you said that your query is giving the correct result and your actual problem is just the performance, I would start replacing those left joins for EXISTS using the HAVING to get the data that you already want to return, not to discard...

Your next step is to check that your table is properly indexed

```
 ;WITH 
    Step1 AS ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM MyTable S1
        WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM MyTable 
        WHERE COL_1 = S1.COL_1 AND COL_2 = S1.COL_2 ANd COL_3 = S1.COL_3 
        GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2, COL_3
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 5 )  
    ) , 
    Step2 AS 
    ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM Step1 S1
        WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Step1 
        WHERE COL_1 = S1.COL_1 AND COL_2 = S1.COL_2
        GROUP BY COL_1,COL_2 
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 5 )
    ) , 
    Step3 AS 
    ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM Step2 S2
        WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Step2 
        WHERE COL_1 = S2.COL_1
        GROUP BY COL_1 
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 5 )
    ) 
    SELECT * FROM Step3
```